# Text in content editable div is not showing similar to text in iTextSharp PDF

Tags: jquery, html, css, pdf, itext

I have HTML and JQuery based designer where I write some text in a content editable div and apply fonts settings like color, size and family. When I generate PDF using iTextSharp, text not showing similar to content editable div. I want to say words count in a single line is not same in content editable div and pdf. Fonts settings are applied perfectly in iTextSharp code while generating PDF.

See how text in a div looks like: [image: HTML]

See how text in a PDF looks like: [image: PDF]

What I want is:

Either **PDF text looks similar to div** OR **div text looks similar to PDF**

Can any body help me?

Comment: I would assume that in one case you use kerning and in one you don't.

Comment: Some other suggestion ???

Comment: Amedee Van Gasse, can you please help me about the mentioned problem ???

Comment: VistaPrint "www.vistaprint.com" has no issues like that.

Comment: Soofian, you merely show some images and no code, not even a hint to any implementation details. As no one sees the code, no one can seriously tell how how to improve it. (Ok, at least you did show the images which made the problem quite clear; there are questions without even that...)

Comment: That been said I don't know the fine details of html layout, so I most likely won't recognize the cause of the difference even with code. I would *assume* differences in use of kerning data or rounding issues.